# How To Install Chrome Driver In Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I am trying to run a `python` script on cloud shell,I have already installed python on it but i need chrome driver to properly run the project. Is there any way to install chrome driver via cloud shell? Also, is there any way to install any linux distro via cloud shell?